# Web2py tab completion in ipython doesn't work for db and db.Field (DAL)

Tags: web2py, ipython

Ipython Code completion SEEMS to be working for web2py BUT it is leaving off suggestions and the very ones that i think are most helpful:

- **after db.tab,** tables **is NOT listed in the suggestions.**
- **after db.mytable.tab,** fields **is NOT listed in the suggestions.**

What am i missing? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is ipython session illustrating what i mean.

```
E:\web2py>python web2py.py -M -S exp2
web2py Web Framework
Created by Massimo Di Pierro, Copyright 2007-2011
Version 1.99.2 (2011-09-26 06:55:33) stable
Database drivers available: SQLite3, pymysql
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]: db.
db.Field                          db.__module__                     db.get
db.Table                          db.__ne__                         db.has_key
db.__call__                       db.__new__                        db.import_from_csv_file
db.__class__                      db.__reduce__                     db.import_table_definitions
db.__cmp__                        db.__reduce_ex__                  db.items
db.__contains__                   db.__repr__                       db.iteritems
db.__delattr__                    db.__setattr__                    db.iterkeys
db.__delitem__                    db.__setitem__                    db.itervalues
db.__dict__                       db.__sizeof__                     db.keys
db.__doc__                        db.__str__                        db.parse_as_rest
db.__eq__                         db.__subclasshook__               db.pop
db.__format__                     db.__weakref__                    db.popitem
db.__ge__                         db._update_referenced_by          db.rollback
db.__getattr__                    db.check_reserved_keyword         db.set_folder
db.__getattribute__               db.clear                          db.setdefault
db.__getitem__                    db.commit                         db.smart_query
db.__gt__                         db.copy                           db.update
db.__hash__                       db.define_table                   db.values
db.__init__                       db.distributed_transaction_begin  db.viewitems
db.__iter__                       db.distributed_transaction_commit db.viewkeys
db.__le__                         db.executesql                     db.viewvalues
db.__len__                        db.export_to_csv_file
db.__lt__                         db.fromkeys

In [1]: db.tables
Out[1]:
['auth_user',
 'auth_group',
 'auth_membership',
 'auth_permission',
 'auth_event',
 'auth_cas',
 'su']

In [2]: db.su.
db.su.__call__             db.su.__iter__             db.su._create_references   db.su.iteritems
db.su.__class__            db.su.__le__               db.su._drop                db.su.iterkeys
db.su.__cmp__              db.su.__len__              db.su._filter_fields       db.su.itervalues
db.su.__contains__         db.su.__lt__               db.su._insert              db.su.keys
db.su.__delattr__          db.su.__module__           db.su._listify             db.su.on
db.su.__delitem__          db.su.__ne__               db.su._truncate            db.su.pop
db.su.__dict__             db.su.__new__              db.su._validate            db.su.popitem
db.su.__doc__              db.su.__reduce__           db.su.bulk_insert          db.su.setdefault
db.su.__eq__               db.su.__reduce_ex__        db.su.clear                db.su.truncate
db.su.__format__           db.su.__repr__             db.su.copy                 db.su.update
db.su.__ge__               db.su.__setattr__          db.su.drop                 db.su.update_or_insert
db.su.__getattr__          db.su.__setitem__          db.su.fromkeys             db.su.validate_and_insert
db.su.__getattribute__     db.su.__sizeof__           db.su.get                  db.su.values
db.su.__getitem__          db.su.__str__              db.su.has_key              db.su.viewitems
db.su.__gt__               db.su.__subclasshook__     db.su.import_from_csv_file db.su.viewkeys
db.su.__hash__             db.su.__weakref__          db.su.insert               db.su.viewvalues
db.su.__init__             db.su._build_query         db.su.items                db.su.with_alias

In [2]: db.su.fields
Out[2]: ['id', 'k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6', 'k7', 'sufile', 'function']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just committed to trunk a change in web2py that will resolve your issue for db.tables and db.table.fields. Thanks for spotting this problem. If you find other attributes that are not displayed let me know and I will try address it. Please use the web2py mailing list or the google code web2py issue tracker to report this problem so we do not have to hunt for them on various places. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

IPython's tab completion of attributes is based on `dir` (with a little extra sugar), so it won't find attributes that only exist on request via custom `__getattr__`, which is especially common for proxy/remote object code, and presumably how web2py defines the attributes missing from completions.

I don't know of a way to inspect these things other than establishing a convention for how to define the available names.

An example class, which has working `cat` and `car` attributes:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = 'tabby'
        self._car = 'edsel'

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'car':
            return self._car
        else:
            raise AttributeError(attr)
```

but tab-completing on instances of this class will only ever show `cat`, because `car` is only defined when it is requested.

For more information, see the attribute-match code [for the completer](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/rel-0.12/IPython/core/completer.py#L357), and the [slightly extended](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/rel-0.12/IPython/utils/dir2.py) version of dir used therein.

Comment: You can work round this by adding custom completer for the relevant objects. E.g. I added this code for pandas: https://github.com/wesm/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3676